# Datalist Pattern with Jsf 2 and CDI

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, cdi

I've an class like...

```
@RequestScoped
public class UserList
...
public List<User> getUserList(){
  return getEntityManager().createQuery(getCriteria()).getResultList();
  //getCriteria() hard query need userType parameter to be populated
}
}
```

All pages can call this class, but each on with different parameter, like "userType=A". The values of these parameter stay on each Managed Bean(Conversation Scoped) of each page.

How  or when populate the DataList parameter?
There is a pattern for dataList with jsf2 and CDI?

Answer (score 0):

JSF doesn't provide a data-list component out of the box. You can however create your own (look into `<ui:repeat/>`) or use one of the component libraries out there - Tomahawk, PrimeFaces, RichFaces, to name a few.

As for the parameter - simply inject your conversation scoped bean into the request scoped bean and read it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing this in the get method is very bad. You'll notice this method being called many times and will slow do page rendering. What you should do is fetch the data in a `@PostConstruct` method and set it on a member variable, then in your get method simply return that variable.

Comment: Ok. By the way, the parameters will be populate like @rdcrng says, is it?